# MPI Создание коммуникаторов

Tags: c++, распараллеливание, mpi

Мне необходимо разделить процессы на несколько коммуникаторов. В один записать четные, а в другие нечетные. Написал код, но при выполнении сыпятся ошибки. Помогите разобраться в чем пробелема. Есть мнение, что необходимо использовать MPI_Comm_split(), но я не пойму как мне правильно это сделать

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <mpi.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    int errCode;

    if ((errCode = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv)) != 0)
    {
        return errCode;
    }

    int world_rank, world_size;
    int *odd, *even;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    int oddSize = world_size / 2;
    int evenSize = world_size - oddSize;
    odd = new int[oddSize];
    even = new int[evenSize];
    MPI_Comm odd_comm, even_comm;
    MPI_Group group11, group12, group13, group21, group22, group31, group32, odd_group, even_group, group_world;
    MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &group_world);


    for (int i = 0, j = 0, p = 0; i < world_size; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            odd[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            even[p] = i;
            p++;
        }
    }


    MPI_Group_incl(group_world, oddSize, odd, &odd_group);
    MPI_Group_incl(group_world, evenSize, even, &even_group);

    MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, odd_group, &odd_comm);

    int row_rank, row_size, size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(odd_comm, &row_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(odd_comm, &row_size);

    if (world_rank == 0)
        cout << "Rank = " << row_rank << " Size = " << row_size << endl;/**/

    MPI_Comm_free(&odd_comm);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
    }
```

Появляются ошибки такого вида

```
job aborted:
[ranks] message

[0] terminated

[1] fatal error
Fatal error in MPI_Comm_rank: Invalid communicator, error stack:
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_NULL, rank=0x0111FC70) failed
Invalid communicator

[2] terminated

[3] fatal error
Fatal error in MPI_Comm_rank: Invalid communicator, error stack:
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_NULL, rank=0x009FFDB8) failed
Invalid communicator

[4] terminated

[5] fatal error
Fatal error in MPI_Comm_rank: Invalid communicator, error stack:
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_NULL, rank=0x00BDF7E4) failed
Invalid communicator

[6-8] terminated

[9] fatal error
Fatal error in MPI_Comm_rank: Invalid communicator, error stack:
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_NULL, rank=0x005FF7C0) failed
Invalid communicator

[10-16] terminated

[17] fatal error
Fatal error in MPI_Comm_rank: Invalid communicator, error stack:
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_NULL, rank=0x00DFFB58) failed
Invalid communicator

[18-29] terminated

---- error analysis -----

[1,3,5,9,17] on DRON
mpi has detected a fatal error and aborted Debug\lab2_1.exe
```

Comment: *"он не отрабатывает"* что вы ожидали получить (конкретный пример)? что вместо этого происходит?

Comment: @jfs Прикрепил скрин с ошибками. А ожидал получить несколько коммуникаторов и работу без ошибок.

Comment: а что там неясно ? @jfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MPI_Comm_create ()` возвращает непустую ручку коммуникатора только членам группы. Остальные получают заглушку `MPI_COMM_NULL`. Так что корректный код будет выглядеть, например так:

```
// ...
MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, odd_group, &odd_comm);

int row_rank, row_size;

if (odd_comm != MPI_COMM_NULL) {
    MPI_Comm_rank(odd_comm, &row_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(odd_comm, &row_size);

    if (row_rank == 0)
        cout << "Rank = " << row_rank << " Size = " << row_size << endl;/**/

} else {
    row_rank = -1; row_size = -1;
}

// ...

if (odd_comm != MPI_COMM_NULL) {
    MPI_Comm_free(&odd_comm);
}
```

В данном случае `MPI_Comm_create ()` создаёт один коммуникатор, общий для указанной группы., но by-design он должен быть вызван из всех процессов родительского коммуникатора (на то есть несколько причин — см. стандарт MPI).

Также для MPI ≥2.2 `MPI_Comm_create ()` может создать сразу несколько коммуникаторов для непересекающихся групп процессов:

```
int *new_grp_members = malloc (grpSz * sizeof(int));

MPI_Group group_world, new_grp;
MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &group_world);

for (int i = 0; i < grpSz; ++i) {
    int num = (i<<1) | is_odd;
    new_grp_members[i] = num;
}

MPI_Group_incl(group_world, grpSz, new_grp_members, &new_grp);
free (new_grp_members);

MPI_Comm odd_even_comm;
MPI_Comm_create (MPI_COMM_WORLD, new_grp, &odd_even_comm);

MPI_Group_free (&new_grp);

assert ( odd_even_comm != MPI_COMM_NULL )

int row_rank, row_size;
MPI_Comm_rank(odd_even_comm, &row_rank);
MPI_Comm_size(odd_even_comm, &row_size);

printf ("WorldRank = %d: LocalRank=%d, LocalSize = %d\n", world_rank, row_rank, row_size);

MPI_Comm_free(&odd_even_comm);
```

В данном случае создаётся по отдельному коммуникатору для чётных процессов и для нечётных. Точно такого же самого эффекта можно добиться с помощью `MPI_Comm_split ()`:

```
MPI_Comm odd_even_comm;
MPI_Comm_split (MPI_COMM_WORLD, world_rank % 2, world_rank, &odd_even_comm);

assert ( odd_even_comm != MPI_COMM_NULL )

// ...
```

Comment: Действительно помогло, спасибо) А можете мне еще логику объяснить, пожалуйста ?) Вот у меня 30 процессов и каждый процесс выполняет один и тот-же код, т.е. создает группу, потом коммуникатор. Это получится один и тот-же коммуникатор и группа или 30 разных ? я не понимаю

Comment: @АлексейМедведев, добавил в ответ